# Adding timeout while fetching server certs via python

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to fetch a list of server certificates using the Python standard SSL library to accomplish this. This is how I am doing it:

```
import ssl
from socket import *

urls = [i.strip().lower() for i in open("urls.txt")]
for urls in url:
    try:
        print ssl.get_server_certificate((url, 443))
    except error:
        print "No connection"
```

However for some URLs, there are connectivity issues and the connection just times out. However it waits for the default SSL timeout value (which is quite long) before timing out. How do I specify a timeout in the `ssl.get_server_certificate()` method? I have specified timeouts for sockets before, but I am clueless as to how to do it for this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html):

```
SSL sockets provide the following methods of Socket Objects:

gettimeout(), settimeout(), setblocking()
```

So should just be as simple as:

```
import ssl
from socket import *

settimeout(10)

urls = [i.strip().lower() for i in open("urls.txt")]
for urls in url:
    try:
        print ssl.get_server_certificate((url, 443))
    except (error, timeout) as err:
        print "No connection: {0}".format(err)
```

Comment: Got the following error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'settimeout' .I saw in the docs that this was introduced in python 2.7.9 and my version is 2.7.3.Could that be the issue ?

Comment: instead of `ssl.settimeout` try just using the sockets timeout by replacing that line with just `settimeout(10)` (should be imported from socket already).

Comment: NameError: name 'settimeout' is not defined  was the error I obtained..However..setdefaulttimeout(3) method worked..Anyways thanks for pointing me in the right direction..

Comment: setdefaulttimeout(3) needed without ssl.setdefaulttimeout(3), however, ssl module still hanging 1% of time in connect _ssl_wrap_socket_impl -> ssl.py __init__ self.dohandshake() self._sslobj.dohandshake().  python 2.7.18.  different machine with python 2.7.12 doesn't do this, go figure.

Comment: setdefaulttimeout seemed to work for me, edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

This versions runs for me using with Python 3.9.12 (hat tip @bchurchill):

```
import ssl
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)

urls = [i.strip().lower() for i in open("urls.txt")]
for url in urls:
    try:
        certificate = ssl.get_server_certificate((url, 443))
        print (certificate)
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"No connection to {url} due to: {err}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Python 3.10 [`ssl.get_server_certificate` takes `timeout` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.get_server_certificate).

```
import ssl
from socket import *

urls = [i.strip().lower() for i in open("urls.txt")]
for urls in url:
    try:
        print(ssl.get_server_certificate((url, 443), timeout=YOUR_TIMEOUT))
    except error:
        print("No connection")
```